# SQL Query to Count who has the highest number of match victories

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a simple database which will allow me to track snooker results, producing head to head results between players. Currently I have 3 tables: (Player, Fixture, Result)

```
PlayerID    PlayerName
1           Michael Abraham
2           Ben Mullen
3           Mark Crozier

FixtureID   Date                 TableNo    Group
1           07/12/2015 19:00:00  12         0
2           08/12/2015 12:00:00  9          0

ResultID    FixtureID   PlayerID    FramesWon
1           1           1           3
2           1           3           1
3           2           1           2
4           2           3           5
```

As you can see in the Result table, Player1 has played Player3 two times, with Player1 winning the first match 3-1, and Player3 winning the second match 5-2. I would like a query which returns the total number of matches won between the two players. In this case the expected output should be:

```
PlayerID    MatchesWon
1           1
3           1
```

Any help would be appreciated - I'm not even sure if this can be achieved via a query

Comment: The best answer here will use Windowing functions. It will be tough in MySql, which _still_ doesn't have windowing function 12 years after they were added to the ansi standard.

Comment: Are draws possible? Should they be shown in the results? If so, how?

Comment: Draws are possible - but would only occur rarely, hence I'm focusing on the win/loss results - but it is certainly I will be looking to incorporate as well, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree using windowing function would be best way to go if available (SQL Server for example) 
Might be possible with a straight SQL method this way (given that the one having most wins in a "fixture" is the match winner)

```
    SELECT PlayerId, FixtureID, Count(*) As MatchesWon
    FROM Result r 
    WHERE r.Frameswon = (SELECT MAX(frameswon) FROM Result r2
                  WHERE 
                  r.FixtureId = r2.FixtureId)
    GROUP BY PlayerID,FixtureId
```

OR if can leave out the fixtureId, and filter for just the 2 players something like this one as well. with data given above should bring the sample results.

```
    SELECT PlayerId, MatchesWon 
    FROM
    (
    SELECT FixtureID,PlayerId, Count(*) As MatchesWon
    FROM Result r 
    WHERE r.Frameswon = (SELECT max(frameswon) FROM Result r2
                  WHERE 
                  r.FixtureId = r2.FixtureId)

   GROUP BY FixtureId,PlayerID
   ) s
   WHERE 
   PlayerID IN (1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work for you:

```
select playerid, count(*) as matcheswon
from result as r1
where frameswon = 
 (
   select max(frameswon)
   from result as r2
   where r2.fixtureid = r1.fixtureid
   )
group by playerid
```

In a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60821/2

Answer (score 0):

This is the alternative you can try.

```
SELECT r.PlayerID, COUNT(r.PlayerID)
FROM (
    SELECT FixtureID, MAX(FramesWon) AS FramesWon
    FROM `result`
    GROUP BY FixtureID    
) win
INNER JOIN result r ON win.FixtureID = r.FixtureID AND win.FramesWon = r.FramesWon
GROUP By r.PlayerID
```